# How to set date to Datepicker text box in edit case

Tags: jquery

How to set date to Datepicker text box in edit case.

I wrote below code for create date

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#txtDate').datepicker({
 format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
 autoclose: true,
 todayHighlight: true
 });
});
```

And now,
how to set previously set date in datepicker ?

I tried like below,
$("#txtDate").datepicker().datepicker('setDate', Date);
and 
$("#txtDate").val(Date);

Comment: post your html markup so we can help you see whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(function() {
   $( "#Start_Date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-m-yy',
  showOn: "button",
  buttonImage: "../I/cal.gif",// you add your own image in your folder for date
  minDate:'<?php echo $minDate; ?>',
  maxDate:'<?php echo $maxDate; ?>',
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  firstDay:1,
  minDate: -0,
  beforeShowDay: checkDisabled,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  beforeShow: function(input, inst)
  {         inst.dpDiv.css({marginTop: -input.offsetHeight + 'px', marginLeft: input.offsetWidth-210 + 'px'});        }});

  });
```

Try the above script in your JS and #Start_Date will be your id of input tag

Comment: Hi Aravaind, Thankyou for your quick reply, but i need to set previously selected date to datepicker textbox in edit case.

Comment: Add the below line in your body onload funtion                                                    document.getElementById("From_Date").value=PrevSelectedDate;

Comment: #From_Date will be your input id of date

Comment: Hi I tried like  $("#txtDate").val(Date); date is set to textbox, but after click text box it is changing to todays date.

Comment: $("#txtDate").val()=PrevSelectedDate;    //PrevSelectedDate is your previous selected date

Answer (score 0):

try this.this might solve your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#txtDate").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```